# Multiline TextBox sizing issue when put inside a Grid row with Height=Auto

Tags: xaml, uwp

I just ran into a weird glitch with a *TextBox* with *AcceptsReturn="True"*.
When placed inside a *Grid* row with *Height=Auto*, the TextBox seems to have a problem calculating its own layout, actually its height. When the box is focused, it just jerks up and down all the time. What could be causing this and how to work around this?

To reproduce this, create a blank UWP app project and then put the following XAML code inside it. Launch the app (preferably in the SDK emulator): Click the TextBox.. Then click an empty area outside it.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <TextBox xml:space="preserve" AcceptsReturn="True">
            <TextBox.Text>
                1
                2
                3
                4
                5
                6
                7
                8
                9
                0
                1
                2
                3
                4
                5
                6
           </TextBox.Text>
       </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's somewhat expected result. You have the first layer getting hit in the measure() arrange() pass being your Auto on your `Grid`. So it's saying "Hey, give the content of this thing the space it needs and no more." Then you're hitting the `ScrollViewer` embedded in your `TextBox` that just doesn't know what the hell it's supposed to be doing. A work-around, set a max height on one of them, or give your row a `*` height, or fix the size somewhere so they're not fighting each other to see who's supposed to win on every LayoutUpdated pass.

Comment: @Chris W. this sounds good, but does not solve the problem, unfortunately. With `MaxHeight` set to 100 on the _TextBox_  and `RowDefinition Height="*"` the glitch is still there, especially when you move the caret to the very bottom of the textbox with the down arrow key.

Comment: Actually, I've already tried many different combinations. And setting  `MaxHeight` on the textbox does not affect the behavior, but just reduces the amplitude. In my real app, I have two rows: `<RowDefinition/>` and `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`. The 1st row hosts a _ListView_, while the 2nd row hosts the _TextBox_ which must grow in height according to the number of lines the user has typed in it (that's the default behavior for a _TextBox_ with `AcceptsReturn="True"`) and vice versa. Looks like an easy task. That's what I thought at first..

Comment: I'll have to swing back to this then when I have free time, there's got to be another culprit.